# Why does Windows have multiple Desktop views?

Tags: windows, desktop

Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, but I didn't find any other related questions. This is something I have *always* wondered but never found an answer to (and something I've never thought to ask until now):

I've always noticed that Windows has multiple, slightly different desktops. For instance, clicking on one of the Desktop shortcuts in the Navigation pane (either under Quick Access or This PC):

[image: shortcut desktop]

Then, you also have this Desktop, which matches more what you would see on the actual desktop (i.e. if you press <kbd>WIN+D</kbd>):

[image: top-level desktop]

Then of course, when you go to `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`, you also have this Desktop:

[image: user-profile file-directory desktop]

Notice the slight difference in the URL/path of these directories for the above folders.

Of course, I know they all look differently, but what is the inherent difference between these? The first and third Desktop both show the same contents - all files I have control over. The second picture shows all the icons on the desktop - including shortcuts in the Public Desktop folder and icons like Recycle Bin.

Is there programatically a difference between these desktops? Or is this simply somehow supposed to make our lives easier? (And if so, why did Microsoft think this was a good idea?)

Comment: Because of Windows remembers the view settings for a folder

Comment: It's to annoy and confuse you.

Comment: The Desktop view without “My computer”, “Recycle bin” and whatnot in it appeared later. IIRC even after Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is just related to the somewhat clumsy way Microsoft shows (or actually hides) the paths you are browsing.

As you said, the three views are actually different from another. Microsoft pretends as they are the same folder, but they aren't. They are just different views, all with a slightly different purpose and way to access it. One view is the 'all desktop', the other just your 'private desktop folder'.

Instead of showing the 'truth' and just honest about the difference, Microsoft tries to hide those 'implementation details' to use and instead just says 'Desktop'. This is confusing at best.

The different view modes (you set, or were set by default) are remembered, adding to the confusion.